Ansible variable saying it is not defined
I am trying to set a fact inside using ansible to see if splunkforwarder was updated when running ansible builtin yum module. Setting these while in "check_mode: true" for the yum module set the facts correctly (true/false), but when I removed "check_mode" from the yum modules, it said they were not defined. . Why am I not able to access these?
rhel7 yum return module:
{
  "started": 1,
  "finished": 1,
  "stdout": "",
  "stderr": "",
  "stdout_lines": [],
  "stderr_lines": [],
  "ansible_job_id": "260844392283.32426",
  "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/260844392283.32426",
  "changed": true,
  "results": [
    "Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7 will be updated\n---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 will be an update\n---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7 will be updated\n---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 will be an update\n---> Package kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7 will be updated\n---> Package kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 will be an update\n---> Package python-perf.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7 will be updated\n---> Package python-perf.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 will be an update\n---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.9.8-7.el7 will be updated\n---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.9.8-7.el7_9.1 will be an update\n---> Package python3-setuptools.noarch 0:39.2.0-10.el7 will be updated\n---> Package python3-setuptools.noarch 0:39.2.0-10.el7_9.1 will be an update\n---> Package splunkforwarder.x86_64 0:9.2.1-78803f08aabb will be updated\n---> Package splunkforwarder.x86_64 0:9.2.2-d76edf6f0a15 will be an update\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n--> Finding unneeded leftover dependencies\nFound and removing 0 unneeded dependencies\n\nDependencies Resolved\n\n================================================================================\n Package            Arch   Version               Repository                Size\n================================================================================\nUpdating:\n kernel-headers     x86_64 3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 rhel-7-server-els-rpms   9.1 M\n kernel-tools       x86_64 3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 rhel-7-server-els-rpms   8.2 M\n kernel-tools-libs  x86_64 3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 rhel-7-server-els-rpms   8.1 M\n python-perf        x86_64 3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7 rhel-7-server-els-rpms   8.2 M\n python-setuptools  noarch 0.9.8-7.el7_9.1       rhel-7-server-els-rpms   397 k\n python3-setuptools noarch 39.2.0-10.el7_9.1     rhel-7-server-els-rpms   629 k\n splunkforwarder    x86_64 9.2.2-d76edf6f0a15    Splunk_Universal_Forwarder\n                                                                           44 M\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nUpgrade  7 Packages\n\nTotal download size: 79 M\nDownloading packages:\nNo Presto metadata available for rhel-7-server-els-rpms\nNo Presto metadata available for Splunk_Universal_Forwarder\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nTotal                                               59 MB/s |  79 MB  00:01     \nRunning transaction check\nRunning transaction test\nTransaction test succeeded\nRunning transaction\n  Updating   : kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64              1/14 \n  Updating   : kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64                   2/14 \n  Updating   : python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7_9.1.noarch                    3/14 \n  Updating   : kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64                 4/14 \nThis looks like an upgrade of an existing Splunk Server. Attempting to stop the installed Splunk Server...\nWarning: Attempting to revert the SPLUNK_HOME ownership\nWarning: Executing \"chown -R root:root /opt/splunkforwarder\"\nStopping splunkd...\nShutting down.  Please wait, as this may take a few minutes.\n [  OK  ]\r\nStopping splunk helpers...\n [  OK  ]\r\nDone.\n  Updating   : splunkforwarder-9.2.2-d76edf6f0a15.x86_64                   5/14 \ncomplete\n  Updating   : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7_9.1.noarch                 6/14 \n  Updating   : python-perf-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64                    7/14 \n  Cleanup    : python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7.noarch                        8/14 \n  Cleanup    : kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64                 9/14 \n  Cleanup    : splunkforwarder-9.2.1-78803f08aabb.x86_64                  10/14 \n  Cleanup    : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch                    11/14 \n  Cleanup    : kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64                  12/14 \n  Cleanup    : kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64             13/14 \n  Cleanup    : python-perf-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64                   14/14 \n  Verifying  : python-perf-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64                    1/14 \n  Verifying  : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7_9.1.noarch                 2/14 \n  Verifying  : splunkforwarder-9.2.2-d76edf6f0a15.x86_64                   3/14 \n  Verifying  : kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64                   4/14 \n  Verifying  : kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64                 5/14 \n  Verifying  : python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7_9.1.noarch                    6/14 \n  Verifying  : kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64              7/14 \n  Verifying  : kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64                 8/14 \n  Verifying  : splunkforwarder-9.2.1-78803f08aabb.x86_64                   9/14 \n  Verifying  : kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64                  10/14 \n  Verifying  : kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64             11/14 \n  Verifying  : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch                    12/14 \n  Verifying  : python-perf-3.10.0-1160.123.1.el7.x86_64                   13/14 \n  Verifying  : python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7.noarch                       14/14 \n\nUpdated:\n  kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7                                 \n  kernel-tools.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7                                   \n  kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7                              \n  python-perf.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7                                    \n  python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.9.8-7.el7_9.1                                    \n  python3-setuptools.noarch 0:39.2.0-10.el7_9.1                                 \n  splunkforwarder.x86_64 0:9.2.2-d76edf6f0a15                                   \n\nComplete!\n"
  ],
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "lock_timeout": 400,
      "update_cache": false,
      "disable_excludes": null,
      "exclude": [],
      "allow_downgrade": false,
      "sslverify": true,
      "disable_gpg_check": true,
      "conf_file": null,
      "use_backend": "auto",
      "state": "latest",
      "disablerepo": [],
      "releasever": null,
      "skip_broken": false,
      "cacheonly": false,
      "autoremove": false,
      "download_dir": null,
      "enable_plugin": [],
      "installroot": "/",
      "install_weak_deps": true,
      "name": [
        "*"
      ],
      "download_only": false,
      "bugfix": false,
      "list": null,
      "install_repoquery": true,
      "update_only": false,
      "disable_plugin": [
        "subscription-manager"
      ],
      "enablerepo": [],
      "security": false,
      "validate_certs": true
    }
  },
  "rc": 0,
  "msg": "Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.\n",
  "changes": {
    "updated": [
      [
        "kernel-headers",
        "3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64 from rhel-7-server-els-rpms"
      ],
      [
        "python-setuptools",
        "0.9.8-7.el7_9.1.noarch from rhel-7-server-els-rpms"
      ],
      [
        "python-perf",
        "3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64 from rhel-7-server-els-rpms"
      ],
      [
        "splunkforwarder",
        "9.2.2-d76edf6f0a15.x86_64 from Splunk_Universal_Forwarder"
      ],
      [
        "kernel-tools-libs",
        "3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64 from rhel-7-server-els-rpms"
      ],
      [
        "python3-setuptools",
        "39.2.0-10.el7_9.1.noarch from rhel-7-server-els-rpms"
      ],
      [
        "kernel-tools",
        "3.10.0-1160.125.1.el7.x86_64 from rhel-7-server-els-rpms"
      ]
    ],
    "installed": []
  },
  "_ansible_no_log": null,
  "attempts": 4,
  "failed_when_result": false
}

rhel8 yum return data structure
{
  "started": 1,
  "finished": 1,
  "stdout": "",
  "stderr": "",
  "stdout_lines": [],
  "stderr_lines": [],
  "ansible_job_id": "905324806035.844347",
  "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/905324806035.844347",
  "msg": "",
  "changed": true,
  "results": [
    "Installed: systemd-udev-239-82.el8_10.2.x86_64",
    "Installed: splunkforwarder-9.2.2-d76edf6f0a15.x86_64",
    "Removed: splunkforwarder-9.2.1-78803f08aabb.x86_64",
    "Removed: systemd-udev-239-82.el8_10.1.x86_64",
    "Removed: systemd-udev-239-82.el8.x86_64"
  ],
  "rc": 0,
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "name": [
        "*"
      ],
      "state": "latest",
      "disable_plugin": [
        "subscription-manager"
      ],
      "lock_timeout": 400,
      "allow_downgrade": false,
      "autoremove": false,
      "bugfix": false,
      "cacheonly": false,
      "disable_gpg_check": false,
      "disablerepo": [],
      "download_only": false,
      "enable_plugin": [],
      "enablerepo": [],
      "exclude": [],
      "installroot": "/",
      "install_repoquery": true,
      "install_weak_deps": true,
      "security": false,
      "skip_broken": false,
      "update_cache": false,
      "update_only": false,
      "validate_certs": true,
      "sslverify": true,
      "allowerasing": false,
      "nobest": false,
      "conf_file": null,
      "disable_excludes": null,
      "download_dir": null,
      "list": null,
      "releasever": null
    }
  },
  "_ansible_no_log": null,
  "attempts": 35,
  "failed_when_result": false
}

rhel7 error:
{
  "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'changes'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/roles/patching/tasks/update_with_reboot.yml': line 324, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n## Handle Splunk here ##\n- name: Check if SplunkForwarder was updated RH7\n  ^ here\n",
  "_ansible_no_log": false
}

rhel8 error:
{
  "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'results'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/roles/patching/tasks/update_no_reboot.yml': line 360, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  failed_when: false\n- name: Check if SplunkForwarder was updated RH8\n  ^ here\n",
  "_ansible_no_log": false
}

Yum code for rhel7/8 and trying to set the variable
- name: "Install Latest yum packages"
  yum:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
    disable_plugin: subscription-manager
    lock_timeout: 400
    disable_gpg_check: true
  async: 2000
  poll: 0
# check_mode: true
  register: yum_result_rh7
  when: 
    - 'ansible_distribution_major_version == "7"'
- name: "Install Latest yum packages"
  yum:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
    disable_plugin: subscription-manager
    lock_timeout: 400
  async: 2000
  poll: 0
# check_mode: true
  register: yum_result_rh8
  when: 
    - 'ansible_distribution_major_version == "8"'

- name: Check if SplunkForwarder was updated RH7
  set_fact:
    splunk_updated7: "{{ 'splunkforwarder' in yum_result_rh7.changes.updated | map(attribute=0) | list }}"
  when: 
    - yum_result_rh7 is defined
    - ansible_distribution_major_version | int == 7
- name: Check if SplunkForwarder was updated RH8
  set_fact:
    splunk_updated8: "{{ 'splunkforwarder' in yum_result_rh8.results | map('regex_search', 'splunkforwarder') | select('string') | list }}"
  when: 
    - yum_result_rh8 is defined
    - ansible_distribution_major_version | int == 8


I tried the code that I inserted, and I was expecting a true/false but it skipped the task because of an error

In order to run it in check mode, you have to remove/comment out async and uncomment check_mode



Do you run the ansible command with check (i.e -C)?

I am not sure what you mean. I am running this in Ansible Automation Platform and I am not using check mode @ha36d

You are running your taks in async poll: 0, yet you are not waiting for them to end. You want to run an async_status, somewhere there: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0

So your issue is "simply" that you are trying to process a result that is not yet registered since the command populating the said result has not ended yet.

I don't believe so. You see the output from the yum module is registered as yum_result_rh7/8. Then I view the data structure output. The async in the yum module is going to wait until yum is finished. @β.εηοιτ.βε

@kmuncie, from the documentation I linked: "When you set poll: 0, Ansible starts the task and immediately moves on to the next task without waiting for a result." (emphasis, mine)

If you still doubt me (you have all rights to), with your check_mode commented, run a - debug: var=yum_result_rh7.finished and a - debug: var=yum_result_rh8.finished; if those yields you 0, those tasks have not finished.

Yes, you are 100% right. The ansible docs link you sent helped me wait for yum to finish and then I registered that and then was able to access the variable from the async_status return variable. @β.εηοιτ.βε
